FadeInImage.assetNetwork - ripple effect - Flutter
I'm loading images from an API using URLs and I need to wrap these images in a clickable InkWell. Some images have high quality, so I've implemented FadeInImage.assetNetwork to display a placeholder image while the final image is being fetched from the API. How can I create a ripple effect over the FadeInImage? If that's not possible, does anyone have alternative solutions?
